# xtext configure generator using configuration file

Tags: xtext

I'm developing a DSL using xtext that is producing different outputs (Typescript and java).

The description files I want to put into a separate project and the generated output should go to two other different projects. To know where the two output projects are located, I need a kind of configuration. The best would be to put this configuration into a separate dedicated file together with the description files under version control.

Is there maybe a way to serve the content of the `org.eclipse.xtext.generator.OutputConfigurationProvider` from a configuration file ?

Do you may have a best practice to realize that ?

Thank you in advance,
Michael

Comment: did you have a look at the default mechanism to configure this through eclipse preferences which will be stored as prefs file in the projects .settings folder

Comment: Yes, you're right. Putting the .settings file under source control is sufficient. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Xtext already supports this through preferences in Eclipse. It is stored in a DSL specific prefs file in the .settings folder of the project. So if you use this it will work out of the box